# Get UUID from Arduino Nano, ATmega328

Tags: arduino-nano

I need to know how to obtain the UUID from an Arduino Nano ATmega328 for a project.

Comment: Why not program a UUID in EEPROM once? There **is no hardware UUID**. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559264/unique-machine-id-for-arduino-project

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a UUID.

You only get a UUID in the USB-enabled chips, like the ATMega32U4.

You would have to create your own UUID and store it in EEPROM, or embed it within your sketch.